# React Redux RTK invalidateTags: is firing too early

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a Redux endpoint updateItemQuantity: which performs a PATCH method on the backend to update a quantity.

When this is completed. I need to invalidate the "PendingOrder" and "PendingOrders" cache.

However, the cache looks to be getting in invalidated, and therefore the pending orders refreshed BEFORE the backend has updated.

The workaround I have is to use an await queryFulfilled and implement a timout of 3 seconds, THEN invalidate the tags. However this isn't an ideal solution as the PATCH may take longer.

How can I force redux to only invalidate tags AFTER a request has been fulfilled?

```
updateItemQuantity: builder.mutation<Cart.UpdateItemQuantityFunction.ReturnType, Cart.UpdateItemQuantityProps>({
            query: ({
                functionParameters: { csrfToken },
                inputParameters: { pendingOrderItemNumber, pendingOrderNumber, newQuantity }
            }) => ({
                url: `${path}PendingOrderItems(pendingOrderNumber='${pendingOrderNumber}',itemNumber='${pendingOrderItemNumber}')`,
                method: "PATCH",
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    orderQuantity: newQuantity.toString()
                }),
                credentials: "same-origin",
                headers: headers({ csrfToken })
            }),
            async onQueryStarted(props, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
            await queryFulfilled.then(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    dispatch(
                        api.util.invalidateTags([
                            "PendingOrders",
                            { type: "PendingOrder", id: props.inputParameters.pendingOrderNumber }
                        ])
                    );
                }, 3000);
            });
            },
            invalidatesTags: (_result, _error, props) => [
                "PendingOrders",
                { type: "PendingOrder", id: props.inputParameters.pendingOrderNumber }
            ]
        }),
```

Comment: It only invalidates tags after the mutation request is fulfilled. Maybe your backend closes the connection before everything is processed there?

Comment: If that's the case, what's the solution? Do I need to do  manual pessimistic update? Do you have an example?

Comment: Well, either fix the server so it closes the connection after it has processed the data, or essentially do what you did there. You could also build your own `fetchQuery` that just waits for a few seconds after each mutation before it returns the data, but that's not very nice either.

Comment: So do I need queryFullfilled at all? Will should invalidatesTags: fire when the request has been fulfilled anyway?

Comment: What you have here is option #3 - and also valid. But you should be doing either that or invalidatesTags, not both.

Comment: #3 isn't really an option anyway as the customer won't accept the performance overhead. We have a SAP Backend. Any further details on how to go about closing the connection?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a SAP developer, I have no idea how to go about that environment.